# Ejecutar tarea programada en Windows Server

Tags: windows-server

He programado una tarea en Windows Server que se ejecuta todos los días a las 6:00 am, el problema que tengo es que en ocasiones el servidor se apaga y se enciende como a las 8:00 am por lo cual la tarea no se ejecuta y debo ejecutarla de forma manual.

La pregunta es ¿El programador de tareas tiene alguna configuración y como lo puedo hacer para que si el servidor se apagó y no ejecuto la tarea entonces cuando se encienda esa "tarea pendiente" se ejecute?

*No puedo crear la misma tarea pero que se ejecute al encender el servidor porque en ocasiones se reinicia durante el día y quiero que solo se ejecute un vez por día.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega otra tarea programada, usando el mismo comando y que se ejecute una vez al encender el servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como me dejaron en comentarios, agregue una nueva tarea que hiciera lo mismo pero al encender el servidor. Solo realice unos ajustes a la actividad para que no tuviera problemas por duplicidad. Y desde entonces no tengo problemas o no tengo que ejecutar la tarea de forma manual.